# Jquery File Upload JSON ERROR

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

[image]Hi Friends,

I am trying and implement Jquery File Upload and after resolving issue with uploading file into right path and format. I am getting following error:

So can anyone please suggest, how to resolve this issue and which I file of jquery File Upload I should use to perform debug.

Thanks guys and hopefully required small help

Comment: Can you paste the code here......?

Comment: Hi I am using the copied code of provided demo file by jquery file upload https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ and using the Basic PLUS UI tab.